# force yum to install package with broken dependency

Tags: yum

I want to install a package with yum, but get:

```
$ sudo yum   install  python-Kivy-examples 
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Setopt argument has no value: nodeps
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-Kivy-examples.x86_64 0:1.8.0-12.2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/kivy for package: python-Kivy-examples-1.8.0-12.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/kivy for package: python-Kivy-examples-1.8.0-12.2.x86_64
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-Kivy-examples-1.8.0-12.2.x86_64 (home_thopiekar_kivy)
    Requires: /usr/bin/kivy
    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I force yum to install the package by ignoring the missing dependency.

Comment: Locate the corruped package, and remove it. Once it is done you can install the package

Comment: There is no corrupt package. There is simply a dependency in the package which I would install which can not fulfilled with any other package. It missing file is a symbolic link which I can make myself. But I have no idea how to install the package or tell to ignore this missing external file.